# Magento 2 Locked Config Values

Tags: magento2, admin, configuration

I'm having a problem with config values being locked in the Magento 2 admin.

I've seen that this can happen when you dump the config, but I didn't do that.

When, You dump it's supposed to update the `config.php`, but my `config.php` has no settings entries, only module enable/disable flags.

`bin/magento app:config:import` returns back **Nothing to import**.

Something broke and I can't undo it.  This only seems to be happening for the Default Scope, and it's not all settings, only the Store Email Addresses settings.  We configured them once, now I can't get back in and change them.

HELP!

Comment: If by settings, you mean DB connection info, that's stored in env.php - the same folder as config.php. And the store emails should be set following : https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/configuration/general/store-email-addresses.html

Answer (score 3):

"dawhoo" was on to something, but it had nothing to do with the DB info.  That config file (`app/etc/env.php`) contains config settings of a sensitive nature and is the place where sensitive config values are dumped if you do an export.  After I inadvertently dumped all settings and locked them all, I recovered by removing the exported values from the `app/etc/config.php` file.  However, the *sensitive* ones were exported to `app/etc/env.php`, which I was not aware of.  We use `git` for deployments and it's advised NOT to have `app/etc/env.php` in `git`, so I didn't even notice the change to the file.

Comment: Both are correct answer, most info does not mention env.php though.

Comment: You saved my day!

Answer (score 3):

open config.php file from **app/etc/config.php** location.

Now remove everything from this file except - modules array like below code :

```
return array [
    'modules' => array [
        'Magento_Store' => 1,
        'Magento_AdminNotification' => 1,
        ...
        ...
        ...
    ],
];
```

then save this file  !!

now after saving this file you need to run below command :

`php bin/magento s:up`

`php bin/magento s:d:c`

`php bin/magento c:f`

you don't required to do import for the same , if you just wanted to unlocked this settings.